# Passando valor de textarea para variável

Tags: php, javascript, textarea

Estou tentando enviar o conteúdo de uma textarea para outra página, conforme código abaixo:

```
       <textarea id="mensagem" rows="8" cols="100" maxlength="500" style="border-radius: 6px; resize:none;width: 90%;height: 65px; margin:0 auto;">
    ESCREVA ALGO AQUI
      </textarea>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="sendMSG">Enviar</button>

                    <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#sendMSG").click(function(){

                        var url = "enviamsg.php";
                        var email = "<?php echo $_SESSION['email']?>";
                        var msg = $('#mensagem').val();
                        alert("teste");
                        $.post(url,{postemail:email,postmsg:msg},
                        function(result) {
                            $("#result").html(result); // Só pra verificar retorno
                        });

                    });
                });

            </script>
```

Ao clicar no botão, nada acontece. Imagino que o problema seja na chamada do botão pois já tentei comentar algumas linhas e deixar apenas alguns alerts, e mesmo assim nada aconteceu.
 Alguém saberia identificar onde estou errando?

Obrigado.

Comment: Pode ser algum erro de sintaxe, no console do navegador, algum erro é apresentado?

Comment: Usei seu mesmo código com um `enviamsg.php` retornando sempre 1 e funcionou corretamente. Só criei um `div`com id `result` e fixei o e-mail para não ler a sessão.

Comment: você adciou ao seu código o jquery? verificou se a url está indo para o  caminho cero, pois você não especificou o caminho  absoluto do site testei aqui está tudo funcionando  https://jsfiddle.net/f5jchgz9/ lembre o  codigo tem que vir depois do jquery e coloque a url absoluta de seu site exempo.com/enviamsg.php

Comment: o problema era que estava faltando incluir o código jquery no topo da página... foram de grande ajuda, muito obrigado !